# Modify admin.py so that it's only offering the current logged-in user for the models.ForeignKey(User)

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a blog where more users should log in via admin-panel and publish some content.
My problem is that i only want to allow the user to publish under his username.

My models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ...
```

How should the admin.py or models.py be modified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, [exclude](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.exclude) the author field from the admin form. Then add the logged in user as author in the admin [save_model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) method:

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ['author',]

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if obj.author is None:
            obj.author = request.user
        obj.save()
```

Comment: Right approach, although I'm not sure why you're using `getattr` here - `if not obj.author` would be fine.

Comment: Why not just setting `obj.author = request.user` without `if` statement?

Comment: @UlfricStorm: Doing it without the if statement would update the author every time the object is saved in admin. Using the if statement ensures that the author is only added on object creation